# A way to push terminal prompt to top of screen without deleting history

Tags: bash, terminal, iterm2

I am looking for a way to be able to do something like `command k`, without deleting the history of my terminal. I want to a way to push the terminal prompt to top of the screen without deleting history.

Comment: I believe `clear` will do exactly that. [manpage here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"clear" will do that.

It will remove everything from the window, but leave the history of the session untouched.

Comment: auuuhh amazing. Thank you. I don't know why I couldn't find this on the interwebs. #noob